# How would you uniformly instance meshes along polycurve?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am pretty new to geometry nodes and I have no idea how to do this. I have a simple poly curve and I need to instance objects along this curve.
This is what i need:

[image: Desired result]

Could anyone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: just use a resample curve node with type length

Comment: I can't find a concrete example at the moment, but this question has already been asked (and answered) here in countless variations. Please use the search to find the post that helps you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgeometry-nodes%5D+align+instances+curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, all you would actually have to do is divide the curve at its points, resample the individual segments, and instantiate your objects at those points.

It might look like this:

[image]

Here I split the curve using a series of nodes (`Extrude Mesh` > `Split Edges` > `Separate Geometry` > `Mesh to Curve`), because if you just apply `Split Edges` to a mesh and then convert it back to a curve, you end up with a single spline again.

After that I resample the separated segments, capture the endpoints with `Capture Attribute` and convert the curves directly into points, so that I get the required rotation for an instantiation of the objects at the intermediate points of the segments.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.6+)*</sub>